# If a form is edited on the backend and then synced with the server, will the edited form be reflected on the frontend?

Tags: commcare

If I edit forms on the backend of CommCare (via Manage Forms) and those form edits affect case properties, will those edits be reflected on the front end (i.e. on the tablets) for users who own those cases/forms?

Answer (score 1):

At present the cases that get updated from editing a form will not be re-synced to the users phone.

Answer (score 0):

The sync should update the case properties to be the current state on HQ, which should reflect any edited forms.